# Any way to check or not the checkbox according to the value that arrives? Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

When the data arrives directly, the table is filled in, and I cannot tell you that if "A" arrives it is checked and if "D" arrives, no.

```html
 re(ref: getrefactormodel, contador:number){
      let datos= this.fb.group({
           word_to_rename: [ref.word_to_rename, Validators.required],
           renowned_word: [ref.renowned_word, Validators.required],
           name:[ref.name, Validators.required],
           id:[ref.id, Validators.required],
           activecheck:[ref.activecheck, Validators.required]
         });
       this.refactorFormGroupItemsArray.insert(contador,datos);
   }
```

Like there is some way to put in the input that if value is A be checked if it is D no.

```
<input  type="checkbox"  formControlName="activecheck" value="D" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

checkbox is true/false value even you have set as string when you change it again the value will be either false or true.

```js
 re(ref: getrefactormodel, contador:number){
      let datos= this.fb.group({
           word_to_rename: [ref.word_to_rename, Validators.required],
           renowned_word: [ref.renowned_word, Validators.required],
           name:[ref.name, Validators.required],
           id:[ref.id, Validators.required],
           activecheck:[ref.activecheck == 'D' ? true : false , Validators.required]
         });
       this.refactorFormGroupItemsArray.insert(contador,datos);
   }
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-okvbua)

> some angular component libraries has a components like checkbox the
>   behave the way you want I been use primeng check their component
>   [here](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/checkbox)

Answer (score 0):

You can used the [checked] operator which accepts a Boolean. try something like;

```
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="activecheck == 'A'">
```

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work out for me          <input  type="checkbox"  formControlName="activecheck" [checked]="activecheck == 'A'" value="D" />

Comment: Try without the value="D"